# subprocess.call stopped working suddenly

Tags: python, subprocess

I was working with subprocess.call() and passing command line arguments. It all worked fine initially. But now with the same code, I am not getting any output and a non-zero return value is obtained.  What can be the reasons? It seems weird and I am confused. please give me some insights.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["perl","./program.pl",'-m',"mode",input,output])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can share this code with us?

Comment: A non-zero return value suggests that the program you are calling exited with an error. Double-check the input that you are giving it to see if it hasn't changed.

Comment: Earlier the same program worked. In command prompt  its still working.

Comment: Are you still in the same directory as before? That `./program.pl` line will look in the directory you're currently in, not the directory your Python code is in. Depending on which non-zero return value it is (please tell us what the return value is, as @runDOSrun asked), it could be that Perl can't find the `program.pl` file because you're in a different directory than when you tried it before.

Comment: The return value was 22.

Comment: for debugging try: ```subprocess.check_output(["perl","./program.pl",'-m',"mode",input,output], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)``` https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: I checked it  and got the error as shown:Traceback (most recent call last):
 
  File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['perl', 'c:/ParsCit-master//bin//citeExtract.pl', '-m', 'extract_header', 'c:/ParsCit-master//bin//Fuzzy11.txt', 'c:/ParsCit-master//bin//Fuzzy11head.xml']' returned non-zero exit status 22

Comment: I am stuck with this. Please help.